# What is the correct way to create "tgz" file in python?

Tags: python, linux, compression, tar, freebsd

I use code that below to create tgz file. When I try to exract tgz file after compress, then I have problem on Linux. But when I try on FreeBSD, it extracts successfull.

```
import tarfile
import os


def create_tgzfile(output_filename, source_dir,item_list):
    os.chdir(source_dir)
    tar = tarfile.open(output_filename+".tar.gz", "w")
    for name in item_list:
        tar.add(name)
    tar.close()


create_tgzfile("test","./",["file1","file2"])
```

test.tgz

exract on FreeBSD

```
tar -xzvf test.tgz
x file1
x file2
```

exract on Linux

```
tar -xzvf test.tgz
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

So, why it doesnt open on Linux or How to create correct tgz file with python?

Comment: You created *just* a `.tar` file, you did not compress the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please try using

```
tar = tarfile.open(output_filename+".tar.gz", "w:gz")
```